# PHP post how to get values of options inside a foreach loop to display the selected value

Tags: php, html, post, foreach

I have 5 rooms in a table for a guest house and a user must check the room or rooms they wish to book, and select the options they wish to have like the number of people, the breakfast option, dinner option and bed option.

Let's say we call the 5 rooms in order of appearance:

Element Room

Earth Room

Water Room

Air Room

Fire Room

I get option the results if I select the rooms in top to bottom order like Element to Fire rooms, but I get 0 if I select any room inbetween. The room's name always displays correctly when checking them from checkbox, but the option values display 0, except for the first room (Element)

HTML:

```
<form class="booking-form" name="book-room-form" action="" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate>

<?php foreach ( $rooms as $room ) : ?>

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="room-selected[]" value="<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>">

<select class="num-person select-update" id="<?php echo 'r-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="people-select[]" required>
  <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
  <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
  <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
</select>

<select class="num-dinner select-update" id="<?php echo 'd-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="dinner-select[]">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
    <option value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
    <option value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
</select>

<select class="num-bf select-update" id="<?php echo 'b-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="breakfast-select[]">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Breakfast Type</option>
    <option value="70">Basic Breakfast R70</option>
    <option value="120">Full Breakfast R120</option>
</select>

<select class="bed-select" name="bed-select[]">
    <option selected>Select Bed Size</option>
    <option value="King Bed">King Bed</option>
    <option value="2 Single Beds">2 Single Beds</option>
</select>



<?php endforeach; ?>

    <button name="submit-request" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

CODE:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-request'])) {

    $room_selected = $_POST['room-selected'];
    $numPeople = $_POST['people-select'];
    $dinnerSelect = $_POST['dinner-select'];
    $breakfastSelect = $_POST['breakfast-select'];
    $bedSelect = $_POST['bed-select'];

    $room = $room_selected;
    $num = $numPeople;
    $dinn = $dinnerSelect;
    $bf  = $breakfastSelect;
    $bed = $bedSelect;

    foreach ($room as $id => $key) {
    //$key returns the room name
      if($key) {
        $result[$key] = array(
            'num_person'  => $num[$id],
            'dinner' => $dinn[$id],
            'breakfast'    => $bf[$id],
            'bed_type' => $bed[$id],
        );
    }

    echo $key . '<br/>' . $num[$id] . '<br/>' . $dinn[$id] . '<br/>' . $bf[$id] . '<br/>' . $bed[$id] . '<br/>' ;

    }

}
```

I want to be able to select any room and have the option values displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say its because your not using any keys in your html form arrays.  The current solution is a bit fragile so you either need to be more specific in the field naming or include the key in the array.

```
<?php foreach ( $rooms as $room ) : ?>

<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="room-selected[]" value="<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>">

<select class="num-person select-update" id="<?php echo 'r-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="people-select[<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>]" required>
  <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
  <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
  <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
</select>

<select class="num-dinner select-update" id="<?php echo 'd-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="dinner-select[<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>]">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
    <option value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
    <option value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
</select>

<select class="num-bf select-update" id="<?php echo 'b-' . $room->ID; ?>" name="breakfast-select[<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>]">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Breakfast Type</option>
    <option value="70">Basic Breakfast R70</option>
    <option value="120">Full Breakfast R120</option>
</select>

<select class="bed-select" name="bed-select[<?php echo $room->post_title; ?>]">
    <option selected>Select Bed Size</option>
    <option value="King Bed">King Bed</option>
    <option value="2 Single Beds">2 Single Beds</option>
</select>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then when running your loop instead of checking for $id use the $key.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit-request'])) {

    $room_selected = $_POST['room-selected'];
    $numPeople = $_POST['people-select'];
    $dinnerSelect = $_POST['dinner-select'];
    $breakfastSelect = $_POST['breakfast-select'];
    $bedSelect = $_POST['bed-select'];

    $room = $room_selected;
    $num = $numPeople;
    $dinn = $dinnerSelect;
    $bf  = $breakfastSelect;
    $bed = $bedSelect;

    foreach ($room as $id => $key) {
    //$key returns the room name
      if($key) {
        $result[$key] = array(
            'num_person'  => $num[$key],
            'dinner' => $dinn[$key],
            'breakfast'    => $bf[$key],
            'bed_type' => $bed[$key],
        );
    }

    echo $key . '<br/>' . $num[$key] . '<br/>' . $dinn[$key] . '<br/>' . $bf[$key] . '<br/>' . $bed[$key] . '<br/>' ;

    }

}
```

Comment: I have done that. The problem is that when I select the first room it is all good, if I select first room and second room, all good etc. But if I select first room and fourth room for example, The first room's output is correct but the fourth room gives 0 on options, but the name does display

Comment: Is that after the id is entered into the field name variable like this 'people-select[$id]'

Comment: After entering those values in the name attributes I get absolutely no results from the dropdown values, only the names of the rooms I have checked

Comment: Ok I just realised for your room_selected your using the value of the post_name as the value.  I will amend my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, same results. Could the problem be in my foreach loop where I post the results? I have been on this for three days and I don't understand, I am not sure if I am maybe not looping correctly.

Comment: Your latest edit returns blank values for dropdowns, but the room names still appear

Comment: Yes apologies, I noticed you were using a different field to the id in the checkbox.  I have updated my answer.  So now you are saving the results of the select in an array by using the post_name as the key.  So $_POST['people-select']['Element Room'].  So when we loop the $room-selected we need to use the $key variable instead of the $id.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I will mark your answer as the correct one :) thanks so much

Comment: No problem … got there in the end :)